# Websocket messages geetting lost

Tags: java, spring-mvc, stomp, spring-websocket

I am facing a weird issue in which my messaged dont reach broker intermittently. 
I am using spring stomp relay handler and sockJS. I enabled debug logging for the same and found that
in cases where messages dont reach broker, MESSAGE command is not fired.

> 2014-10-09 15:36:20 DEBUG brokerChannel-26
>   org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler
>   Forwarding message to broker 2014-10-09 15:36:20 DEBUG
>   reactor-tcp-io-2 org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompEncoder
>   Encoded STOMP command=SEND
>   headers={destination=[/topic/recieversdb755d
>   e9-7a6e-47d2-a61d-5401cbe46301],
>   content-type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}

And I continuosly get the following log :

> org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompDecoder Received
>   incomplete frame. Resetting buffer.

Couldnt find anything on net. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a rather complex issue. Could you create a repro project with minimum code and create an issue there: jira.spring.io. To easily create a repro project, don't hesitate to use https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework-issues and submit a PR there. It's all explained in the README. Don't forget to elaborate a bit more your setup: spring version, broker you're using, is it related to a specific browser...

Comment: @Brian In my case I temporary resolved this problem using a minor delay in socket call from UI. There seemed to be a race condition between   TCP connection establishment between server and broker and messages being pushed to broker. I dont have concrete theory for my solution. Thanks for your suggestion, I will create a repro project as mentioned.